# Validation of Combobox, radio buttons, regular buttons etc?

Tags: xpages

I am using the ErrorMessage control on my form to validate things like Edit Boxes.  Works great.  The little gray alert type box pops up when data entry is needed.

Can anyone point me to an example of how I can do the same for radio buttons, combo boxes etc?  Or even a regular button (say I have a add document button on the form).

I really don't care how the message is actually displayed.  I would just like for my validation to be consistent across validation of all of my components.   In other words I  do not want some server side and some client side validation.

Any examples out there?  I have been using my own validation using a ext lib dialog box, that has worked well,  but I was hoping for something easier to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been using an extended version of [this XSnippet on validation](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ssjs-form-validation-that-triggers-errormessage-controls). This makes it possible for you to manage all your validation in a central SSJS library and then display all errors in a Display Errors control.

In the central SSJS library you can then validate your controls including radio buttons, combo boxes etc. and combine your validations (e.g. to check for the value of one control when another control has a certain value).

Here's an example baesd on the mentioned XSnippet of validating whether a certain field (FieldA) has been filled in when a radio button group (radioField) has the value 1:

```
var radioVal = getComponent("radioField").value;
var control = getComponent("FieldA");
var val = control.getValue();
if (radioVal == "1" && isEmpty(val)){
  valid = false;
  postValidationError(control, "Please fill in ...");
}
```

Comment: I think you meant this one? http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ssjs-form-validation-that-triggers-errormessage-controls   I have never been able to get it to work. Are there any working examples out there?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I link to in my answer. I use it in several apps so I have working examples.

Comment: I got it working but I do not like it.  It does not set the focus to the control being validated.  Or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: The point is that you validate several controls in that central script library, and then display validation error messages for all the failed controls in a Display Errors control. Have a look at this if you want to extend the Display Errors functionality: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.dk/2011/07/custom-control-for-enhanced-validation.html

Comment: Thanks.   This is a nice alternative but I think I am going to go back to my original validation.   I like being able to set focus to the control in error.

Answer (score 3):

I hope by ErrorMessage control you mean "Display Error" control. For combo box in All Properties inside 'data' you will find 'validators'. Here you can add your validations just like you do for edit boxes. For combo box I generally use `validateExpression`. I then use the 'Display Error' control to display errors.

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateExpression message="Please select value in combo box.">
            <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:!getComponent("comboBox1").getSubmittedValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Select")}]]></xp:this.expression>
        </xp:validateExpression>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="Select"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:comboBox>
<xp:message id="message1" for="comboBox1"></xp:message>
```

In the above example if user does not select any item in combo box then the error message is displayed to user. Note that this is a server-side validation. I haven't tried it for other controls but it should work in similar manner.

Let me know if I understood your question correctly.

**Update 7 Feb 2013:** Have a look at comment below by Mikael Grevsten for a better way.

Comment: You could leave the itemValue for "Select" option to an empty string and it will validate as empty and an error will be displayed ; <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></xp:selectItem>

Comment: @MikaelGrevsten: Yes, that worked. Thanks! When I used to enter values in combo box via Values tab in Properties the generated XPage code was `<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Select"></xp:selectItem>` without the `itemValue` attribute. This generated HTML code as `<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>` because of which I used `validateExpression`. I should probably look into XPage source more often :)

Comment: Good! I usually type "* Select an option *" as the first entry in the combo with a value if "0" and then remove the zero in the source...

Answer (score 0):

Was able to validate a group of radio buttons by using @GetField and the name of the group.

In this example, the group name was BankLoss:

```
// BankLoss
var radio1 = @GetField("BankLoss")
if (radio1 == null || radio1 == ""){
    valid = false;
    errors.push("Please indicate if there was a potential bank loss.");
}
```

Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Even simplest and straightforward: If you have an option like "Select an option" and set the empty value "", you can use **validateRequired**, and that's it. 
Example:

If combobox values are:

```
["-Select an option-|","Text1|Value1","Text2|Value2"]
```

You can, as @Naveen said, go to All Properties > data > validators > + > ValidateRequired > Set your **message** and you're done.